# How to write a "style" view modifier that affects all the nested views of a certain type?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm basically trying to create something similar to the built-in `buttonStyle`, `labelStyle` etc modifiers. They affect all the nested buttons/labels, no matter how deeply nested they are. e.g.

```
VStack {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            Button("OK") {}
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
.buttonStyle(.bordered) // this changes the style of the button, even if it is deeply nested
```

My goal is to do the same with my custom view. Let's call it `TwinTextsView`:

```
VStack {
    VStack {
        VStack {
            TwinTexts(text1: "Foo", text2: "Bar")
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
.twinTextsStyle(CustomStyle()) // this changes the style of TwinTexts, even if it is deeply nested
```

where `CustomStyle` can be implemented like a `ButtonStyle`, with a `makeBody` method taking in a configuration with two views, representing the texts

```
struct TwinTextsStyleConfiguration {
    // not sure what types these should be. AnyView?
    let text1: Text1
    let text2: Text2
}

protocol TwinTextsStyle {
    associatedtype Body: View
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func makeBody(configuration: TwinTextsStyleConfiguration) -> Body
}

struct CustomStyle: TwinTextsStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: TwinTextsStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
        // let's suppose I want to put one text on top of the other.
        VStack {
            configuration.text1
            configuration.text2
        }
    }
}
```

This style will then be used by `TwinTexts` like this:

```
struct TwinTexts: View {
    let text1: String
    let text2: String
    
    var body: some View {
        // note that these are not of type "Text". I don't know what type they are as I will be adding view modifiers to them
        // here I am using lineLimit as an example 
        let text1 = Text(text1).lineLimit(1)
        let text2 = Text(text2).lineLimit(1)
        // not sure how I would get the "style" here
        style.makeBody(.init(text1: text1, text2: text2))
    }
}
```

One idea I thought of is using a custom `Environment`, since `.environment` applies to all the nested views. There are two problems:

- `style.makeBody` would return `any View`, which can't be used in `body`

```
struct TwinTextsStyleKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: any TwinTextsStyle = DefaultStyle()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var twinTextsStyle: any TwinTextsStyle {
        get { self[TwinTextsStyleKey.self] }
        set { self[TwinTextsStyleKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension View {
    func twinTextsStyle(_ style: some TwinTextsStyle) -> some View {
        self.environment(\.twinTextsStyle, style)
    }
}

struct TwinTexts: View {
    let text1: String
    let text2: String
    @Environment(\.twinTextsStyle) var style
    var body: some View {
        let text1 = Text(text1).lineLimit(1)
        let text2 = Text(text2).lineLimit(1)
        style.makeBody(.init(text1: text1, text2: text2)) // this returns "any View"
    }
}
```

- I don't know what types I should use for the views in `TwinTextsStyleConfiguration`.

  I looked at [`ButtonStyleConfiguration.Label`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/buttonstyleconfiguration/label-swift.struct), and according to the docs, this is a "type-erased" view. Is this an actual use case for `AnyView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've implemented several styles and views that can be styled using a similar API to the in-built views, they all follow similar patterns. As Benzy Neez has found, you can quickly get into a tangle with generics.

You are absolutely correct in that this is a perfect use case for `AnyView`. It's impossible at compile time to know:

- What style is currently in force for a given view
- What content view(s) have been passed in to a given instance of the view (if you are allowing arbitrary content using view builders).

The type-erased views you see in the in-built configuration types are, as far as I can tell, functionally identical to `AnyView`.

Your steps to creating a style, and a view that can be styled, are:

**1. Define a protocol representing the style:**

```swift
protocol XXStyle {
    
    associatedtype Body: View
    
    @ViewBuilder 
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) ->      
      Self.Body
    
    typealias Configuration = XXStyleConfiguration

}
```

This is pretty much identical everywhere, just altering XX for your actual name.

**2. Define a configuration type**

```swift
struct XXStyleConfiguration {
    let viewContent: AnyView
    let modelContent: ??
}
```

This type should contain everything the style implementation needs to render. If you're passing in things with view builders, you'd store them as `AnyView`. If you have things like strings, store them as strings here.

**3. Environment and view modifier chores**

Styles live in the environment, because that's how you get a modifier applied once to a container to be detectable by all views inside that container. Make a key for your style, with a default value of some automatic or built-in implementation of your style protocol:

```swift
struct XXStyleKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: any XXStyle = DefaultXXStyle()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var xxStyle: any XXStyle {
        get { self[XXStyleKey.self] }
        set { self[XXStyleKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Add view modifiers to apply this automatically so you can use it like `.buttonStyle()`.

```swift
extension View {
    func xxStyle(_ style: any xxStyle) -> some View {
        self.environment(\.xxStyle, style)
    }
}

extension XXStyle where Self == ThisXXStyle {
    static var this: Self { ThisXXStyle() }
}
```

**4. View implementation**

Define your view as follows:

```swift
struct XX<ViewContent: View>: View {

    @Environment(\.xxStyle) private var style
    let configuration: XXStyleConfiguration
    init(_ modelStuff: ??, @ViewBuilder content: () -> ViewContent) {
        configuration = .init(
            viewContent: .init(content()), 
            modelContent: modelStuff)
    }

    var body: some View {
        AnyView(style.makeBody(configuration: configuration))
    }
}
```

Pass in the data and / or views that form your implementation, and store them in the configuration which you create on init. Then get the style from the environment, which at compile time is `any` style, get the body from it, then wrap it in `AnyView` so the type system doesn't explode.

It's quite a process, but it does work, and I don't feel bad about the use of `AnyView` here because it's exactly what the in-built views like `Button` are doing, even if you don't apply a style.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you gave `.buttonStyle` and `.labelStyle` as examples of modifiers that can be applied at the parent level and impact the views at lower levels. In both these cases, the styles apply to very specific types of views, namely `Button` and `Label`. In the world of design patterns, I would describe these styles as **Decorators**. It is worth noting that the types of the target views do not change after they have been decorated, they are still `Button` and `Label`.

On the other hand, I would say the code you gave in outline is more of an example of a **Builder**, because it is trying to work with generic content. I was thinking it might be possible to get it to work by using generics, but when I tried it I got tied up with the handling of `some View` and couldn't even get it to compile.

Exhausted from fighting the protocols and generics, I took a step back and realized that if you have full control over the code base then there would be an altogether simpler way to solve the problem. This is to put all the knowledge of the different styles into `TwinTexts` and just switch between them. This makes `TwinTexts` the Builder. If the different styles would be complex then `TwinTexts` could delegate to specilaized implementations, but the switching logic would remain in `TwinTexts`. So all that is needed to identify the different styles is an `enum`:

```swift
enum TwinTextsStyle {
    case any
    case horizontal
    case vertical
}

struct TwinTextsStyleKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = TwinTextsStyle.any
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var twinTextsStyle: TwinTextsStyle {
        get { self[TwinTextsStyleKey.self] }
        set { self[TwinTextsStyleKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension View {

    // Makes the style available to sub-views
    func twinTextsStyle(_ style: TwinTextsStyle) -> some View {
        self.environment(\.twinTextsStyle, style)
    }
}

// The View TwinTexts combines two views together in the way
// defined by the environment value twinTextsStyle
struct TwinTexts<Text1: View, Text2: View>: View {
    let text1: Text1
    let text2: Text2
    @Environment(\.twinTextsStyle) var style

    private var horizontalStyle: some View {
        HStack {
            text1
            text2
        }
    }

    private var verticalStyle: some View {
        VStack {
            text1
            text2
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        if style == .horizontal {
            horizontalStyle
        } else {
            verticalStyle
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                VStack {
                    TwinTexts(
                        text1: Text("Foo").lineLimit(1),
                        text2: Text("Bar").lineLimit(1)
                    )
//                    ...
                }
//                ...
            }
//            ...
        }
        .twinTextsStyle(.horizontal) // this changes the style of TwinTexts, even if it is deeply nested
    }
}
```

As you can see, your original requirement of being able to apply a modifier at a higher level to control the styling at a lower level is satisfied. However, what this approach does not give you is the ability to add new custom styles when you do not have control of the Builder.

Comment: "Exhausted from fighting the protocols and generics", I feel your pain :)