# Using lineLimit on Label vs. ForEach in SwiftUI: Why do both work?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been working on a SwiftUI widget and came across an interesting observation.

I've always used `.lineLimit(1)` directly on the Label to limit the number of lines it displays:

```
struct TodoWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    let todoItems: [TodoItem] = DataManager().todoItems
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
            ForEach(0..<todoItems.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Button(intent: TodoIntent(item: todoItems[index].taskName)) {
                    Label(todoItems[index].taskName, systemImage: "circle\(todoItems[index].isCompleted ? ".fill" : "")")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        .lineLimit(1) // Applied directly on Label
                }.tint(.black)
            }
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }.background(SwiftUI.Color.fromInt(0xfff7ce46))
    }
}
```

However, I later realized I could also apply `.lineLimit(1)` to the end of `ForEach`:

```
struct TodoWidgetEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    let todoItems: [TodoItem] = DataManager().todoItems
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
            ForEach(0..<todoItems.count, id: \.self) { index in
                Button(intent: TodoIntent(item: todoItems[index].taskName)) {
                    Label(todoItems[index].taskName, systemImage: "circle\(todoItems[index].isCompleted ? ".fill" : "")")
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }.tint(.black)
            }
            .lineLimit(1) // Applied on ForEach
            Spacer(minLength: 0)
        }.background(SwiftUI.Color.fromInt(0xfff7ce46))
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why applying `.lineLimit(1)` to the `ForEach` is also effective in limiting the lines of the labels inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *lot* of view modifiers in SwiftUI are designed this way - applying the modifier to an "outer" view will apply the same modifier to all the views "nested" inside that view. Other than `lineLimit`, there is also `environment`, `font`, `multilineTextAlignment`, `foregroundStyle`, the various view-specific style modifiers like `buttonStyle`, `pickerStyle`, `toggleStyle`, and so on.

For `lineLimit` specifically, the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/linelimit(_:)-513mb) points this out:

> The line limit applies to all `Text` instances within a hierarchy. For example, an `HStack` with multiple pieces of text longer than three lines caps each piece of text to three lines rather than capping the total number of lines across the `HStack`.

You can make this kind of modifiers yourself by using `environment`, which can "trickle down" any kind of value you want. You can start by creating your own `EnvironmentKey` and `EnvironmentValues`.

```
struct FooEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: Int = 0
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var foo: Int {
        get { self[FooEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[FooEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}

extension View {
    func foo(_ number: Int) -> some View {
        environment(\.foo, number)
    }
}
```

Then you can do

```
ForEach(0..<5) { _ in
    SomeView()
}
.foo(5)

// The value of "@Environment(\.foo) var foo" in SomeView would be 5
```

See [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77184515/5133585) for a more complicated example.

Comment: In fact the `lineLimit` modifier itself is implemented via the environment, as evidenced by [the `lineLimit` property of `EnvironmentValues`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/linelimit).