# How to avoid AnyView for enum with function returning a View in a Strategy Pattern?

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, enums

I found no other way than using AnyView in the following code, using the strategy pattern for selecting a WorkingViewStyle. Is my code an example where AnyView must be used? I see no way to use some View as a return type for the concrete implementations of WorkingViewStyle.

```
import SwiftUI

enum ProgressStatus {
    case starting(String)
    case working(String, count: Int? = nil, total: Int? = nil)
    case finished(String)
}

struct StatusView: View {
    let progressStatus: ProgressStatus?
    var workingViewStyle: WorkingViewStyle = BasicWorkingViewStyle()

    
    var body: some View  {
        VStack {
            switch progressStatus {
            case .starting(let string):
                Text("\(string)")
            case .working(let string, let count, let total):
                workingViewStyle.workingView(string: string, count: count, total: total) 
            case .finished(let string):
                Text("\(string)")
            case nil:
                Text("\u{200B}")
            }
        }
    }
}


protocol WorkingViewStyle {
    func workingView(string: String, count: Int?, total: Int?) ->  AnyView
}

struct BasicWorkingViewStyle: WorkingViewStyle {

    func workingView(string: String, count: Int?, total: Int?) -> AnyView {
        AnyView (
            HStack {
                if let count, let total {
                    Text("\(string) \(count)/\(total)")
                } else {
                    Text(string)                    
                }
            }
        )

    }
}
#Preview {
  
    List {
        StatusView(progressStatus: .working("Lorem ipsum dolor"))
        StatusView(progressStatus: .working("Lorem ipsum dolor", count: 3, total: 10), workingViewStyle: BasicWorkingViewStyle())
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Yes. You need `AnyView` for this kind of thing. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/77184515/5133585